# How can I tell Time Machine to keep using its former backup?

Tags: macos, time-machine

For some reason Time Machine doesn't think that the backups on my external drive are for my current computer.

How can I point Time Machine at the former backup files so it can pick up where it left off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On OS X 10.7 Lion or later, yes. You need to look at the `tmutil` command, specifically the `inheritbackup` verb (which tells Time Machine that this is a backup of *this* machine, and not some other), and the `associatedisk` verb (which tells Time Machine that the disk it *was* backing up before is this other disk that you have now).